# Which Linux program writes failed sshd login attempts to /var/log/btmp Centos 7

Tags: linux, logging, centos7, pam, sshd

Failed ssh attempts are being logged to /var/log/btmp except attempts with a username where the account exists on the server e.g. root.

Initially I thought a module within /etc/pam.d/sshd handles btmp logging and may be filtering the attempts somehow, but I could only find information on successful login attempts [pam_lastlog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_lastlog)

Am I looking in the correct area, sshd -> pam -> logfile?

Is it likely a filter is applied to ignore exiting user attempts?

Note: I have password and root ssh login disabled.  Running Centos 7

Comment: Please don't add your answer in the question.

Comment: @paper1111 Hi sorry I'm new to posting, where's the correct location?  The answers below aren't correct to the question.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom, there is a text box which allows you to write your answer and post it.

Comment: Completely missed that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case sshd is responsible for writing failed login attempts to /var/log/btmp file.

Quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp)

> These files are not set by any given PAM module (such as pam_unix.so or pam_sss.so) but are set by the application performing the operation (e.g. mingetty, /bin/login, or sshd). As such it is the obligation of the program itself to record the utmp information.

Confirmation of the above can be found online, such as this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/743858)

Although PAM is not responsible for writing to /var/log/btmp, [pam_lastlog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_lastlog) can write to /var/log/wtmp (a record of logins and logouts), and can read from /var/log/btmp

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sshd fails and success logins are logged in "/var/log/audit/audit.log".
below log file extract help you to understand how it works

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1531228962.485:1069): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="**root**" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=**192.168.0.16** addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=**success**'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1531228962.488:1070): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1531228962.489:1071): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=session fp=? direction=both spid=4488 suid=74 rport=50181 laddr=**192.168.0.10** lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1531228962.490:1072): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=success acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1531228962.491:1073): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1531228962.491:1074): pid=4487 uid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 old-auid=4294967295 auid=0 old-ses=4294967295 ses=27 res=1
type=USER_ROLE_CHANGE msg=audit(1531228962.653:1075): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='pam: default-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 selected-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1531228962.669:1076): pid=4487 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_selinux,pam_namespace,pam_keyinit,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_lastlog acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1531228962.675:1077): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=fd:b6:92:76:06:cb:7d:47:02:9f:5d:a9:78:d9:8b:f0 direction=? spid=4493 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=pts/4 res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1531228962.675:1078): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=21:5c:ac:e6:f7:ec:c1:b8:61:b7:d1:90:30:8c:9e:8c direction=? spid=4493 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=pts/4 res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1531228962.675:1079): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=fa:be:5c:4d:09:b2:b0:85:d3:67:43:d0:5e:54:5b:1d direction=? spid=4493 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=pts/4 res=success'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1531228962.677:1080): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1531228962.677:1081): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
type=CRED_REFR msg=audit(1531228962.678:1082): pid=4493 uid=0 auid=0 ses=27 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=192.168.0.16 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

Here is the failed log extract

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1531228891.558:1025): pid=4245 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.168.0.16 addr=**192.168.0.16** terminal=ssh res=**failed**
```

Comment: You've indeed answered the question, but it's a different log file than I was inspecting.  auditd does indeed writes login failures into the audit.log file.  But I'm still unsure how /var/log/btmp is written to, and if it's created from audit.log

Comment: I think below link will help you to understand who btmp written. 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed this line:

_"These files are not set by any given PAM module (such as pam_unix.so or pam_sss.so) but are set by the application performing the operation (e.g. mingetty, /bin/login, or sshd). As such it is the obligation of the program itself to record the utmp information."_

Answer (score 0):

/var/log/messages

you can control it by fail2ban utility.

i have implemented and its worked fine.

Xaman

Comment: I don't feel as though I need another layer such as fail2ban or Denyhosts etc.. the system is logging (most) attempts however, I'm trying to find out **why failed attempts from user names which exist on the server** are **not being logged** under under /var/log/btmp (failed attempt log), thanks!

Comment: check var/log/messages file

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but there are not any records of failed attempts.  As @damithudayanga mentioned auditd has a log of the failed attempts, but not in the location I mentioned.  I've updated my question title to reflect that.